# Can't build with Cordova and Sencha command

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I have lately installed Keybaord soft plugin for cordova(android) and after that I was not able to build the project at ALL ! So how to fix the error below .
PS: I have tried everything uninstall for the plugin ,remove the platforms and re-install cordova again.

```
[INF] [shellscript] [getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.1
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/****/projects/****/****/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:422: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/****/projects/****/****/.sencha/app/cordova-impl.xml:118: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/home/****/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.2.67/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:608: shellscript returned: 1
```

Comment: use the debug mode when building your app: `sencha -d app build native` so you will get more information about the error

Comment: Have you tried if the build still works? Had the same error message and my project actually runs fine even with compile error.